# Mysql priority condition with where clause

Tags: mysql

I try to check two conditions when checking first condition if it is true then ignore second condition. if first condition false then check second condition.

here query like this

```
select * from region_daten inner join werte_inc where datum = today or datum = yesterday"
```

[image: table looks like this]

here returns today and yesterday because both are true but before 11:30 am i have only yesterday date after 11:30 am i have both dates. when i do with 'or' i got both dates data. but i need to show if date is today date i have to display today date data. if not i have to display yesterday data.

Comment: Simple `OR` should suffice.

Comment: OR should return if both are true but i i need if first condition true no need to check second condition. I need to get only one condition either first or second.

Comment: `OR` returns true if at least one of the conditions is true. I think this is exactly what You need. If `date = today`, you want `true`, `OR` gives You that. If `date <> today`, then You want to check the other condition, in this case `OR` gives You exactly the boolean value of the second condition. Try writing down all four possibilities and then try evaluating them with Your "else" algorithm and then with the "or" and see for Yourself.

Comment: So You want to show only ONE record and only if it is today or yesterday, not older?

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a truth table:

```
date = today | date = yesterday | desired result
-------------+------------------+---------------
true         | true             | true
true         | false            | true
false        | true             | true
false        | false            | false
```

If this table is correct according to Your question, then what You are looking for is an OR:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE date = today OR date = yesterday
```

Comment: What you said exactly true that is my mistake to understand actually i got both dates (today and yesterday) data but i need first priority is today if today data not updated then take yesterday data. because my database update today data after 11:00 am upto that time i need to show yesterday data after that when my database update with today date then i have to display that data. after 11:00 am i got both dates in my database it returns today and yesterday data.

Comment: can i use max(date) to get latest date.

Comment: Can You show some example data and desired result, please?

Comment: I did like this select * from region_daten where datum = (select max(datum) from region_daten) when my database update with new date i get updated data.